# Formatting types in Java

Tags: java

```
public class T {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int i = 2345;
        System.out.printf("%0-10d", i);
        System.out.printf("(%-010d)", i);
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain why these two SOP's  are showing run-time error.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to print?

Comment: what is %0-10d here? what are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get runtime error because you provided invalid format pattern.

Some examples from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html):

```
long n = 461012;
System.out.format("%d%n", n);      //  -->  "461012"
System.out.format("%08d%n", n);    //  -->  "00461012"
System.out.format("%+8d%n", n);    //  -->  " +461012"
System.out.format("%,8d%n", n);    // -->  " 461,012"
System.out.format("%+,8d%n%n", n); //  -->  "+461,012"
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use two flags that don't make sense together.

- `-` left justify in the field
- `0` left pads the number with zeroes.

You can't do both.  If you left justify, there is no room for those leading zeroes.

Comment: but we can use two or more flags together right , like this  System.out.printf("(%1$0,10d)", i);

Comment: @Aamir Yes, you could have multiple flags, you just can't have contradictory flags.  You would also run into problems with `%+ 10d` since it doesn't make sense to force a sign *and* insert a space if no sign will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying contradictory flags. The `0` indicates that the output should be zero-padded; the `-` indicates that it should be left-justified. You can't have both.